# Cannot activate SSL on my website

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-18.04

I am currently hosting 4 different websites on my Ubuntu machine with no problem. Problem only appears when I enable or try to enable SSL. I only follow this simplest tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Bo78eDEy7g and basically do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt install python-certbot-apache
certbot --apache -d peytuk.com
```

You can go ahead and see https://peytuk.com is not responding.

I have tried to manually install the certificate before, and failed there as well. I certainly am not an expert on this, so please go easy on me.

Just in case if my ufw status is needed

```
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: It might be wise to add your apache config files to the question.

Comment: Also the exact error message when it "fails".